# typeOf with wildcard in macros

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm trying to get vals with type Option[_]

```
case q"$mods val $vname:$tpt = $expr" if tpt.tpe <:< typeOf[Option[_]] =>
```

but compiler throws exception:

```
[error] Macros.scala:13: exception during macro expansion: 
[error] java.lang.Error: internal error: ? (WildcardType) is not supported
[error]         at scala.reflect.reify.codegen.GenTypes$class.reifyToughType(GenTypes.scala:196)
[error]         at scala.reflect.reify.codegen.GenTypes$class.reifyType(GenTypes.scala:66)
```

Is there some workaround to compare those types?

Comment: It seems to me, you can use `tpt.tpe <:< typeOf[Option[Any]]`, because `Any` is a super type for all types.

Comment: Yep. But anyway could you share the code so that I can take a look at this particular bug?

Comment: @DaunnC what's weird is that i get NPE on tpt.tpe

Comment: @EugeneBurmako code https://gist.github.com/wedens/acd86de71e5605493c8a

Comment: oh, if i understand correctly, i should call c.typeCheck to get tpe. but i get `scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: illegal cyclic reference involving object Test`

Comment: Problem solved with `c.typeCheck(q"(None.asInstanceOf[$tpt])").tpe`